# Spring 4 RestController & Returning JSON

Tags: json, spring, rest, controller, jackson

I have a simple controller, which should return JSON, but is failing to do so. The JSON library is Jackson, configured as a maven dependency. When I make a request using postman, against this url path, I am receiving a 404 error. When I attempt to inspect the JSON Returned, I see "Malformed JSON: Unexpected '<'".

Could someone suggest what it is I am missing / failing to understand? Thank you

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/World/")
public class RestfulController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Country/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Country> findAllCountrys(){
        Country c = new Country(1, "Ethiopia", "Addis Abba", "94 Million");
        return new ResponseEntity<Country>(c, HttpStatus.OK);
    }  
}
```

spring application context

```
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.restfulapp.controller"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: If it could not serialize to json, it would return a 500 Internal Server Error, not 404. Something is wrong with your request mappings or configs

Comment: Based on theses mappings, you should send `GET` requests to `/World/Country/`, not even `/World/Country`

Comment: Basically, those trailing slashes are not good ideas

Comment: Thank you Ali, I've removed the trailing slashes, but still the same outcome. I receive a error "Malformed JSON: Unexpected '<'" when attempting to inspect the json data.

Comment: Now add your full stack trace to your question

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/World")
public class RestfulController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Country", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Country findAllCountrys(){
        Country c = new Country(1, "Ethiopia", "Addis Abba", "94 Million");
        return c;
    }  
}
```

The request url: http://yourhost/World/Country

This should return a json of Country

Comment: Hi Avaid, thank you for your reply. I have tried also this approach to no avail. Strangely enough, the method seems to be returning text/html, as indicated in the response header:

Comment: Content-Language → en
Content-Length → 987
Content-Type → text/html;charset=utf-8
Date → Mon, 11 Jan 2016 00:24:02 GMT
Server → Apache-Coyote/1.1

Comment: You need to add one more thing i forgot. @ResponseBody on the method under requestMapping. Can you try that?

Comment: Hi Avaid, thank you for your suggestion. As I am using @RestController annotation, this should combine both Controller & ResponseBody, so this step is now obsolete. Thank you

Comment: And if you are just returning String "Hello world"? What is the output.